# mysql cursor fetch without declaring variables (possible?)

Tags: mysql, cursor

I have a cursor which is declared as so:

```
DECLARE staging_cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
col1, col2, ......
FROM crawl_db.staging_listing
WHERE is_deleted = FALSE;
```

I then fetch each row, perform some checks and then insert the row into another (production) database

```
OPEN staging_cur;
the_loop: LOOP

  FETCH staging_cur
  INTO col1_val, col2_val,.....;

  -- perform some checks and some optional inserts
      -- for example, if city with given name is not found in production DB, insert it

  -- insert into production db

END LOOP the_loop;
```

I realize I need to declare a variable (`col1_val, col2_val ...`) for each corresponding column of table staging_listing (`col1, col2....`). The problem is that this table contains 90-100 columns and declaring all variables is really cumbersome

It seems there should be a better way than this. Is there some way in which we can access the column of the cursor's current row without having to declare separate variables to hold the column values?

Comment: what is your purpose for the variables?

Comment: some of them are used in the 'perform some check' step. most of them are used in the 'insert into production db' step.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to insert rows into another table, then a better way is to use INSERT...SELECT statement. Try to avoid using cursors.

[INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: actually there are some checks and optional inserts on a per-row basis. based on those optional inserts, we use their auto-generated insert ids in further inserts. (I have updated my question)

Comment: If it is possible - try to use DML statements:INSERT, UPDATE, and etc.; otherwise, you will have to create those variables.